# App getting Crashed when i launch the app

Tags: android

I developed one app and rollout the released in Google Playstore. Around 2L peoples are currently downloaded and using on that app. Recently i faced one issue in my member complaints app automatically closed when i tap the app like launch the app. After that i got the following error in Logcat and given below. Please review it once and share your views if anybody knows.

Note : The same app i uninstall and re-install the app its working well.

**LogCat error :**

```
07-09 18:41:30.683 1364-2332/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.keny/com.bney.login.screen bnds=[381,658][503,780] (has extras)} from uid 10021 on display 0
07-09 18:41:30.708 1364-2729/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 13733:com.keny/u0a459 for activity com.keny/com.bney.login.screen
07-09 18:41:31.505 13733-13733/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting...
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Aborting thread:
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75488fb8 self=0x55bdc12930
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | sysTid=13733 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=1073741825/1 handle=0x7fafd21fc8
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | state=R schedstat=( 654802404 2325424 255 ) utm=59 stm=6 core=1 HZ=100
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | stack=0x7fc6694000-0x7fc6696000 stackSize=8MB
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #00 pc 000000000048d1dc /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+200)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #01 pc 000000000045bb84 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEP12BacktraceMap+228)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #02 pc 0000000000434da0 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+48)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #03 pc 0000000000435120 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+752)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #04 pc 0000000000137cd0 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+3136)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #05 pc 000000000053fe34 /system/lib64/libart.so (artInvokeInterfaceTrampoline+1492)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #06 pc 000000000011e1a8 /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_interface_trampoline+104)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #07 pc 0000000000040d50 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Throwable__0003cinit_0003e__Ljava_lang_String_2+148)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:95)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Error.<init>(Error.java:48)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(VirtualMachineError.java:46)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.bney.login.screen.CustomRunnable(screen.java:2235)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.bney.login.screen.loadVersionCheck(screen.java:1658)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.bney.login.screen.pre_marshmallow(screen.java:3156)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.bney.login.screen.onCreate(screen.java:305)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] All threads:
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] DALVIK THREADS (26):
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75488fb8 self=0x55bdc12930
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | sysTid=13733 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=1073741825/1 handle=0x7fafd21fc8
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | state=R schedstat=( 674796831 2325424 255 ) utm=60 stm=7 core=1 HZ=100
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | stack=0x7fc6694000-0x7fc6696000 stackSize=8MB
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #00 pc 000000000048d1dc /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+200)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #01 pc 000000000045bb84 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEP12BacktraceMap+228)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #02 pc 000000000046933c /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+716)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #03 pc 000000000046a258 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureEb+288)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #04 pc 000000000046aba4 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+204)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #05 pc 0000000000435060 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+560)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #06 pc 0000000000137cd0 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+3136)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #07 pc 000000000053fe34 /system/lib64/libart.so (artInvokeInterfaceTrampoline+1492)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #08 pc 000000000011e1a8 /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_interface_trampoline+104)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #09 pc 0000000000040d50 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Throwable__0003cinit_0003e__Ljava_lang_String_2+148)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:95)
07-09 18:41:31.506 13733-13733/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Error.<init>(Error.java:48)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(VirtualMachineError.java:46)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.bney.login.screen.CustomRunnable(screen.java:2235)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.bney.login.screen.loadVersionCheck(screen.java:1658)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.bney.login.screen.pre_marshmallow(screen.java:3156)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.bney.login.screen.onCreate(screen.java:305)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "Signal Catcher" prio=5 tid=2 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d320a0 self=0x55bdcf4f80
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | sysTid=13738 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fabb4f450
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | state=S schedstat=( 997656 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | stack=0x7faba53000-0x7faba55000 stackSize=1013KB
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | held mutexes=
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/13738/stack)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #00 pc 0000000000069e34 /system/lib64/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+8)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #01 pc 0000000000021ed4 /system/lib64/libc.so (sigwait+44)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #02 pc 0000000000440428 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13WaitForSignalEPNS_6ThreadERNS_9SignalSetE+108)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #03 pc 0000000000441b14 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+276)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #04 pc 00000000000677c4 /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #05 pc 000000000001c644 /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   (no managed stack frames)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "ReferenceQueueDaemon" prio=5 tid=3 Waiting
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d2cdc0 self=0x55bde6f5f0
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | sysTid=13739 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7faba47450
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | state=S schedstat=( 5750155 140104 24 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=5 HZ=100
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | stack=0x7fab945000-0x7fab947000 stackSize=1037KB
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | held mutexes=
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/13739/stack)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #00 pc 00000000000199c0 /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #01 pc 000000000013b100 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+136)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #02 pc 0000000000396ee0 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadElibNS_11ThreadStateE+1440)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #03 pc 00000000003970d0 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectElibNS_11ThreadStateE+244)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #04 pc 000000000000054c /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__+128)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   - waiting on <0x0258a132> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:152)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   - locked <0x0258a132> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "FinalizerDaemon" prio=5 tid=4 Waiting
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d2ce20 self=0x55bdd11c80
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | sysTid=13740 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fab93b450
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | state=S schedstat=( 7722922 61979 114 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | stack=0x7fab839000-0x7fab83b000 stackSize=1037KB
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | held mutexes=
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/13740/stack)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #00 pc 00000000000199c0 /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #01 pc 000000000013b100 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+136)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #02 pc 0000000000396ee0 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadElibNS_11ThreadStateE+1440)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #03 pc 00000000003970d0 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectElibNS_11ThreadStateE+244)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #04 pc 000000000000082c /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__JI+144)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   - waiting on <0x0f860e83> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:423)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:101)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   - locked <0x0f860e83> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:72)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:217)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" prio=5 tid=5 Sleeping
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d2ce80 self=0x55bded2f80
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | sysTid=13741 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fab82f450
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | state=S schedstat=( 742449 24218 14 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=4 HZ=100
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | stack=0x7fab72d000-0x7fab72f000 stackSize=1037KB
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | held mutexes=
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/13741/stack)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #00 pc 00000000000199c4 /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #01 pc 000000000013ab24 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadEli+164)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #02 pc 0000000000396c14 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadElibNS_11ThreadStateE+724)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #03 pc 00000000003970d0 /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectElibNS_11ThreadStateE+244)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   native: #04 pc 00000000000272b4 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Thread_sleep__Ljava_lang_Object_2JI+168)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep!(Native method)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   - sleeping on <0x00d24800> (a java.lang.Object)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   - locked <0x00d24800> (a java.lang.Object)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:985)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(Daemons.java:324)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:346)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:263)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=5 tid=6 Blocked
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d2cee0 self=0x55bded78f0
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | sysTid=13742 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7fab723450
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | state=S schedstat=( 56502814 9237032 41 ) utm=5 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
    art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]   | stack=0x7fab621000-0x7fab623000 stackSize=1037KB
07-09 18:41:32.011 1364-13777/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.keny/com.bney.login.screen
07-09 18:41:32.059 1364-2962/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{a4195ce u0 com.keny/com.bney.login.screen}
07-09 18:42:32.195 1364-3517/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 13841:com.miui.msa.global:ui/u0a131 for service com.miui.msa.global/com.xiaomi.ad.internal.splash.uiprocess.SplashUIService
07-09 18:46:23.281 10098-10109/? W/AD-PLUGIN-RemoteMethodInvoker: Service[interface com.xiaomi.ad.internal.splash.uiprocess.api.ISplashUIInterface, com.xiaomi.ad.internal.splash.uiprocess.api.a@9c4e366] died, remove from reusing-map!
07-09 18:47:41.038 14287-14401/? D/Apptimize: Apptimize: Posting to https://brahe.apptimize.com/api/device/v4/: {"type":"v4","schemaVersion":4,"a":"AdqFynZKhfrtqRzRVNcewTPpatMQbKA","c":1531142261034,"g":"ed5e51cc-ce2d-47dd-a331-aa6340526e3f","o":{"type":"v3","schemaVersion":4,"postCreated":1.531142261034E9,"guid":"ed5e51cc-ce2d-47dd-a331-aa6340526e3f","currentResults":[{"metrics":{},"experimentRunCount":0,"variationId":819091},{"metrics":{"primary_template":6,"chat_form_loaded":58,"mp: discover_select":9,"Select_Ad_Browse":2,"mp: clear_breadcrumb":3,"mp: Choose_Search":4,"posting_loaded":1,"mp: Choose_location_category":2,"mp: splash_displayed":2,"Select_Ad_Search":72,"mp: homepage_loaded":2,"Successful_Post":1,"mp: search_result_click":4,"reply":3,"Tap_Message":3,"mp: App_open":1,"ChatReply":4,"mp: listing_load":20,"mp: Select_Ad":4,"editing_loaded":2,"mp: search_recommend_tap":4,"reply2":4},"experimentRunCount":75,"variationId":1423021}],"finalResults":[],"sequenceNumber":5487,"sequenceNumberLastSuccessfulllySent":5478,"metaDataSequenceNumber":720,"deviceProperties":{"system_version":"6.0.1","app_version_code":272,"app_installed_date":1.493877768617E9,"screen_height":1280,"platform":"Android","device_class":"phone","app_version":"6.7.2","app_first_run_date":1493878118,"brand":"Xiaomi","app_language":"en","system_language":"en","screen_width":720,"manufacturer":"Xiaomi","system_country":"IN","system_architecture":"arm64-v8a","user_language":"en","apptimize_version":"3.1.2","screen_scale":2,"apptimize_platform":"Android","model":"Redmi 3S","distribution_method":"store"},"userAttributes":{"country":"in"},"applicableExperimentNames":["Change Placement of Response Templates: OLXIN-1479","Chat: Change Placement of Response Templates V2 : OLXIN-1479","Android Prefetch Google Ads New"]},"e":[{"ei":10630,"mt":1531132548521,"dt":1531132548521,"sb":363241977,"bt":1530769306544,"pa":{"$system_language":"en","mplay_services_status":"available","$app_language":"en","$apptimize_version":"3.1.2","$screen_height":1280,"mplatform":"android","minstall time":"04\/05\/2017:11:38:39","%country":"in","mgaid":"ca160fc6-9f9c-4d43-903a-cf946a685737","mnotifications_enabled":true,"$system_architecture":"arm64-v8a","$distribution_method":"store","$device_class":"phone","$user_language":"en","mtotal opens":291,"$app_installed_date":1.493877768617E9,"mis_cta_shown_on_card":true,"mradial distance":"6","mdevice id":"7ec18592385a9604","mcategory mode":"Search","^v1423021_1":1,"$app_first_run_date":1493878118,"muser id":"31384489","$platform":"Android","mdevice token":"CJy6ovtaGCpEFRrPWSMXe9PhQGvQJeomcaFI4PhyNzukX1QIcd","$model":"Redmi 3S","$brand":"Xiaomi","$app_version_code":272,"$app_version":"6.7.2","$manufacturer":"Xiaomi","$system_version":"6.0.1","msort order":"distance:asc","^e52385_1":1,"$screen_width":720,"mis_category_carousel_shown":true,"$screen_scale":2,"$apptimize_platform":"Android","$system_country":"IN"},"ty":"sp","t":1531132548000,"f":10619,"l":10629},{"ei":10631,"mt":1531132895592,"dt":1531132895592,"sb":363589049,"bt":1530769306544,"ty":"ie","n":"problemInVisual","a":{}},{"ei":10632,"mt":1531132895598,"dt":1531132895598,"sb":363589054,"bt":1530769306544,"ty":"md","s":720,"v":[819091,1423021],"vp":[{"v":819091,"c":1,"p":1},{"v":1423021,"c":1,"p":1}]},{"ei":10633,"mt":1531134164278,"dt":1531134164278,"sb":364857735,"bt":1530769306544,"ty":"ie","n":"problemInVisual","a":{}},{"ei":10634,"mt":1531134164284,"dt":1531134164284,"sb":364857740,"bt":1530769306544,"ty":"md","s":720,"v":[819091,1423021],"vp":[{"v":819091,"c":1,"p":1},{"v":1423021,"c":1,"p":1}]},{"ei":10635,"mt":1531134532475,"dt":1531134532475,"sb":365225931,"bt":1530769306544,"ty":"ie","n":"problemInVisual","a":{}},{"ei":10636,"mt":1531134532481,"dt":1531134532481,"sb":365225937,"bt":1530769306544,"ty":"md","s":720,"v":[819091,1423021],"vp":[{"v":819091,"c":1,"p":1},{"v":1423021,"c":1,"p":1}]},{"ei":10637,"mt":1531134590288,"dt":1531134590288,"sb":365283744,"bt":1530769306544,"ty":"ie","n":"problemInVisual","a":{}},{"ei":10638,"mt":1531134590306,"dt":1531134590306,"sb":365283762,"bt":15307
```

Comment: Whats on screen.java:2235 ?

Comment: This is Android 9 correct?

Comment: Whats on screen.java:2235 ? - First api call initiating when launch the app; Call<DynamicPP> dynamicpopCall = RetroApiCall.getDynamicPAPI(AppState.getInstance().getMemberMatriID()+"~"+Constants.APPVERSIONCODE,
                            Constants.constructApiMap(new UrlParser().UrlGenerator(Constants.New_Asset_version, new String[] {}))
                    );

Comment: This is Android 9 correct?. Its not a 9 Version. Redmi 3S Prime Mobile and Version 6.0.1 and MIUI Version MIUI Global 9.5 Stable

Answer (score 0):

Please set us project structure and code MainActivity from what i read (i am not sure) your error cause some kind of extras in Intent which is creating.
Question is how u closeing app(before u use some pending intent or smth like that?/closeing threads?)
I had similar problem but in my case was unClosed service tring to use variable which was nolonger posible to gain meybe that is your problem also.

Comment: I don't think this is a causing the issue. Because we are not using the Service oriented  in this project. But my problem like when we tap the app icon its immediately close the app and also we got the above error when we call the first api from retrofit.